# Javascript Populated Fields gives Undefined Function Error

Tags: javascript

I am creating a todo app. It consists of 3 task to do with status set to `false` by default. The fields are populated using Javascript.

When the radio button is checked, it should run the `completeTask()` function. But it is giving me the undefined function error. Please Help!

```js
let todoApp = (() => {
 const container = document.getElementById('todoLister');
 const todoList = [
  {
   task: 'Get Up',
   status: false
  },
  {
   task: 'Eat stuff',
   status: false
  },  
  {
   task: 'Goto College',
   status: false
  }
 ];

 todoList.forEach((el, id) => {
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  const radio = document.createElement('input');
  const br = document.createElement('br');

  if(el.status)
   label.innerText = el.task+'- Done Successfully';
  else
   label.innerText = el.task+'- Not Done';
  
  label.setAttribute('for', el.task);
  radio.value = id;
  radio.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
  radio.setAttribute('onchange', 'completeTask('+id+')');
  container.appendChild(radio);
  container.appendChild(label);
  container.appendChild(br);
 });

 let completeTask = (id) => {
  todoList[id].status = true;

  if(todoList[id].status)
   document.getElementsByTagName('label')[id].innerText = 'Done Successfully';
 }
})();
```

```html
<div id="todoLister">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your function inside the `todoApp`, it was not available globally. You need to move your function and data outside the function so as it is visible globally.

```js
const todoList = [{
    task: 'Get Up',
    status: false
  },
  {
    task: 'Eat stuff',
    status: false
  },
  {
    task: 'Goto College',
    status: false
  }
];


let completeTask = (id) => {
  todoList[id].status = true;

  if (todoList[id].status)
    document.getElementsByTagName('label')[id].innerText = 'Done Successfully';
}

let todoApp = (() => {
  const container = document.getElementById('todoLister');


  todoList.forEach((el, id) => {
    const label = document.createElement('label');
    const radio = document.createElement('input');
    const br = document.createElement('br');

    if (el.status)
      label.innerText = el.task + '- Done Successfully';
    else
      label.innerText = el.task + '- Not Done';

    label.setAttribute('for', el.task);
    radio.value = id;
    radio.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    radio.setAttribute('onchange', 'completeTask(' + id + ')');
    container.appendChild(radio);
    container.appendChild(label);
    container.appendChild(br);
  });


})();
```

```html
<div id="todoLister">
</div>
```

Comment: Gotcha! Stackoverflow wants me to wait 5 mins before I can mark this as answer :)

Comment: @Sanjay - Glad to help you :)